# Create diff of collections

Tags: c#, diff

I want to create a "merged diff" of two collection in C# (LINQ). Suppose, the following 2 collection of strings, and the input collections are sorted:

```
a - a
b - c
e - d
```

And the expected output should be:

```
a - a
b - null
null - c
null - d
e - null
```

Now, I have the following implementation:

```
    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T, T>> Diff<T>(IEnumerable<T> a, IEnumerable<T> b, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        List<T> listA = a.ToList();
        List<T> listB = b.ToList();
        int indexA = 0;
        int indexB = 0;

        while (indexA < listA.Count || indexB < listB.Count)
        {
            if (indexA == listA.Count && indexB < listB.Count)
            {
                yield return new KeyValuePair<T, T>(default(T), listB[indexB++]);
            }
            else if (indexA < listA.Count && indexB == listB.Count)
            {
                yield return new KeyValuePair<T, T>(listA[indexA++], default(T));
            }
            else if (comparer.Equals(listA[indexA], listB[indexB]))
            {
                yield return new KeyValuePair<T, T>(listA[indexA++], listB[indexB++]);
            }
            else
            {
                yield return new KeyValuePair<T, T>(listA[indexA++], default(T));
            }
        }
    }
```

That produce the following output:

```
a - a
b - null
e - null
null - c
null - d
```

Can anybody help me, how to fix it (Is there any nuget package that do it out of the box?)

**Update:**

Thank you for @Daniel's answer, it works if collections don't contain duplicated records.

Filter duplicated items or warrant no duplicates are not an option in this case.

The next issue that I have faced to is the following:

Suppose, I have two collections (list of strings):

```
Collection A:    Collection B:
  Apple            Apple
  Apple            Peach
  Peach
```

The actual result looks like:

```
Result Collection
  Apple  -  Apple
  null   -  Peach
  Apple  -  null
  Peach  -  null
```

And what I expect:

```
Result Collection
  Apple  -  Apple
  Apple  -  null
  Peach  -  Peach
```

Is it possible to detect and couple elements in this case?

Comment: Both diffs look plausible... Can you please [edit] question to clarify what's wrong with one you don't like? Also while editing consider the fact that asking for libraries/nugets/other off-site resource is off-topic - https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Can you reword the question so that it's clearer?  I don't understand what's being asked.  what are a, b, c, d, and e?  When you say something like "a - a" what does that mean?  Does it mean a should equal a?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others pointed out in the comments, you might have to reword the question to make it more clear what is the desired output. Making a few assumptions about what you want the "diff merge" to do, my guess is that you need more than just equality comparer. Equality comparer only tells you if things are or are not **equal**. My guess is that you want to compare for **is less than**, **is equal** and **is greater than**.

If you have to provide custom comparer to the method, this is one plausible implementation:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T, T>> Diff<T>(IEnumerable<T> a, IEnumerable<T> b, IComparer<T> comparer)
{
    List<T> listA = a.ToList();
    List<T> listB = b.ToList();
    int indexA = 0;
    int indexB = 0;

    while (indexA < listA.Count || indexB < listB.Count)
    {
        if (indexA == listA.Count && indexB < listB.Count)
        {
            yield return new KeyValuePair<T, T>(default(T), listB[indexB++]);
        }
        else if (indexA < listA.Count && indexB == listB.Count)
        {
            yield return new KeyValuePair<T, T>(listA[indexA++], default(T));
        }
        else
        {
            int comparison = comparer.Compare(listA[indexA], listB[indexB]);
            if (comparison == 0)
            {
                yield return new KeyValuePair<T, T>(listA[indexA++], listB[indexB++]);
            }
            else if (comparison < 0)
            {
                yield return new KeyValuePair<T, T>(listA[indexA++], default(T));
            }
            else
            {
                yield return new KeyValuePair<T, T>(default(T), listB[indexB++]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can ditch the Comparer argument and add a type constraint on T to implement IComparable interface, which would be my preference. Still not all things are clear in your question, so test my answer thoroughly or change the question.

Comment: If you don't think you have enough information to answer the question, then *don't post an answer to the question* until it's clarified to the point you feel it's answerable.  The question says nothing about comparing items for anything other than equality.

Comment: @Servy I was confident enough that I knew what was the OP trying to do, that's why I posted my answer. What I would improve in my answer is stating up front what assumptions am I making. I remember listening to some podcast (with John Skeet maybe?) that figuring out what the OP actually wanted to do even when some information is missing is part of the fun of answering questions on stackoverflo.

Comment: So you spent all of that time in your answer saying that the question is unclear and unanswerable even though you think the question is clear and unambiguous for what reason?  Helping someone figure out what they actually want to ask doesn't mean just posting guesses to questions without adequate information and just *hoping* you're right, it means *helping the question be improved such that it becomes answerable*, and *then* answering it, only once it's been clarified.

Comment: What do you mean by "spent all that time"? Its only the first and last sentences in my answer. OP provided expected output from which I was confident enough I knew what he/she was trying to do and I tried to help him by pointing out that boolean equality is not enough. I can find a lot of SO pages, where the answer says that OP has to do something different than how he is trying to solve or how he is thinking about his/her question. The longer I am looking at my answer the more I think I should just delete first and last sentences. Again, not saying that some claryfication wouldn't help.

Comment: Most of the first paragraph and last paragraph are you explaining the problems with the question, not just the first and last sentence.  It encompasses almost everything other than your code. There's a big difference between saying the question is unclear so you just guessed at what they wanted and are hoping you guessed correctly versus saying that the problem they've *adequately explained* is best solved through a different approach that their initial attempt.  The latter is fine, the former, not.

Comment: Thank you @Daniel,
This is exactly what I have looked for!

Comment: Well @moravas, I am confused by your updated answer, because when I run the code from my answer on "apples and peaches" lists, I get exactly the same output that you say is the **expected** and **not** what you called **actual result**. You can try it here https://dotnetfiddle.net/zo2sV9 .